# Not able to call a method when a feature/marker is selected in OpenLayers

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I am having a map with multiple ol/Feature markers.
When clicking on a marker some code should be executed.

The problem is that I get this error when trying to call a method when a clicked is performed: TypeError: this.methodCall is not a function at Select.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    .......
  this.setMapInteraction();
}

setMapInteraction() {
  var select = new Select({});
  this.map.addInteraction(select);
  select.on('select', function (evt) {
    var selectedString = evt.selected[0].getStyle()[1].getText().getText();
    console.log(selectedString); //Selected string is printed fine.
    this.methodCall();
  });
}

methodCall() {
    console.log("This is not printed");
//Some action I want to perform.
}
```

If someone knows how to solve this or can provide me another approach I would be very happy.

Comment: try something like this   `select.on('select', (evt) =>{
    var selectedString = evt.selected[0].getStyle()[1].getText().getText();
    console.log(selectedString); //Selected string is printed fine.
    this.methodCall();
  });
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `select` callback `this` is the `select` object, so you need to save the scope, for example:

```
setMapInteraction() {
  var select = new Select({});
  this.map.addInteraction(select);
  var self = this;
  select.on('select', function (evt) {
    var selectedString = evt.selected[0].getStyle()[1].getText().getText();
    console.log(selectedString); //Selected string is printed fine.
    self.methodCall();
  });
}
```

or you could bind the callback:

```
setMapInteraction() {
  var select = new Select({});
  this.map.addInteraction(select);
  select.on('select', function (evt) {
    var selectedString = evt.selected[0].getStyle()[1].getText().getText();
    console.log(selectedString); //Selected string is printed fine.
    this.methodCall();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

An "arrow function" could also be used but you might lose compatibility with older browsers

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a context issue:

Try below:

```
setMapInteraction() {
  var select = new Select({});
  this.map.addInteraction(select);
  select.on('select', function (evt) {
    var selectedString = evt.selected[0].getStyle()[1].getText().getText();
    console.log(selectedString); //Selected string is printed fine.
    this.methodCall();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
 map.on('click', function(e) {
  var iconFeatureA = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel);
  if (iconFeatureA !== null) {
    var location = iconFeatureA[0].get("coordinat");
    alert(location);
  }
});
```

this will work with every pixel of your features of map.